# Angular listen for enable/disable elements

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to find out if an element is disabled in an Angular directive.

I am trying with host listeners so far no luck

Directive:

```
 @HostBinding('attr.disabled') isDisabled : boolean;

 @HostListener("disabled") disabled() {
     if(this.isDisabled) {
          // do some action 
     }
 }
```

It's working for me with the setter

```
@Input('disabled')
set disabled(val: string) {
  if(val) {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('disabled', val);
  } else {
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}
```

but I don't want to use the setter because the directive I am developing does not need to enable and disable buttons, it only listens for disable attribute changes.

I want it to be generic of the disable logic.

Comment: `@HostListener` is listening for _events_, there is no `disabled` event. Please clarify you question. If you really need to listen to DOM changes, you probably have to use `MutationObserver`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Dimanoid I want to listen for disabled  attribute changes

Comment: Well, then `MutationObserver` is your only choice I think.

Comment: @Dimanoid Can you just help me with mutationobserver  if you could post the answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way but it works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mutationobserver-test

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTestDir]'
})
export class TestDirDirective {
  observer: MutationObserver;

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
    console.log(_el);
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(
      list => {
        for (const record of list) {
          console.log(record);
          if (record && record.attributeName == 'disabled' &&  record.target && record.target['disabled'] !== undefined) {
            this._el.nativeElement.style.border = record.target['disabled'] ? '2px dashed red' : null;
          }
        }
      }
    );
    this.observer.observe(this._el.nativeElement, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: false,
      subtree: false
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you think it is an overkill to scan the entire Dom for the functionality

Comment: It will listen only to the host element's attributes changes as far as I understood. So it's not too expensive I think.

Comment: good idea to just watch for the disabled attribute using attributeFilter: ['disabled'] in observe()