# Angular directive to handle visibility / enabling given a configuration

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I have the following directive that handles the visibility / enabling of all child elements starting from the element where it's applied to.

In the `ngAfterViewInit`, the directive retrieves the configuration of the elements providing to a web API the componentName attribute and the logged user role. Afterwards the config is applied to all the elements that match a row in the configuration.

```
import {
  Directive, Input,
  ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewContainerRef, Renderer2, DoCheck
} from '@angular/core';
import { CompConfig } from '../model/comp-config';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[limsApplyConfig]'
})
export class ApplyConfigDirective implements AfterViewInit, DoCheck {


  config: CompConfig[];
  compName: string;
  constructor(
    private hostElement: ElementRef,
    private cs: ConfigService,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { }

  @Input() set limsApplyConfig(compName: string) {
    this.compName = compName;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // start with everything hidden: when a config will be received 
    // elements can be enabled following configuration
    this.renderer.addClass(this.hostElement.nativeElement, 'cfg-hidden');

    this.cs.getConfig(this.compName).subscribe(c => {
      this.renderer.removeClass(this.hostElement.nativeElement, 'cfg-hidden');
      this.config = c;
      this.config.forEach(cfg => {
        if (this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll) {
          const inputCollection = this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#' + cfg.ControlName);
          inputCollection.forEach(n => {
            // readonly is a property of inputs
            if (n.readOnly !== undefined) {
              n.readOnly = cfg.Disable;
            }
            // disabled is a property of buttons
            if (n.disabled !== undefined) {
              n.disabled = cfg.Disable;
            }
            if (cfg.Invisible) {
              this.renderer.addClass(n, 'cfg-hidden');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this.config && this.config.length > 0) {
      this.config.forEach(cfg => {
        if (this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll) {
          const inputCollection = this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#' + cfg.ControlName);
          inputCollection.forEach(n => {
            if (n.readOnly !== undefined) {
              n.readOnly = cfg.Disable;
            }
            if (n.disabled !== undefined) {
              n.disabled = cfg.Disable;
            }
            if (cfg.Invisible) {
              this.renderer.addClass(n, 'cfg-hidden');
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

For what concerns the enable / disabled status of the elements I'm having difficulties to make the directive win over the specific logic of the component. The config never changes but the status of buttons / inputs does.

In other words, if a button should be disabled, I want to disable it and **keep it disabled** even if the logic of the component would enable it. Unfortunately I'm not able to do it. I tried adding `ngDoCheck` life cycle-hook but without any success.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55255686/2050306

Answer (score 0):

Directives are evaluated only once until the input changes. If your component is changing the input to the directive [and your component is enabling the button but you still want to disable it via directive then make sure your subscription is executed every time when the input to the directive changes. If my understanding of your problem is correct then let's change the code as follows [please import the necessary classes and pardon for the formatting] -

```
    import {
  Directive, Input,
  ElementRef, AfterViewInit, ViewContainerRef, Renderer2, DoCheck
} from '@angular/core';
import { CompConfig } from '../model/comp-config';
import { ConfigService } from '../services/config.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[limsApplyConfig]'
})
export class ApplyConfigDirective implements AfterViewInit, DoCheck {


  config: CompConfig[];
  compName: string;
  compName$: BehaviorSubject<string>;
  constructor(
    private hostElement: ElementRef,
    private cs: ConfigService,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) { 
   this.compName$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
 }

  @Input() set limsApplyConfig(compName: string) {
    this.compName$.next(compName);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // start with everything hidden: when a config will be received 
    // elements can be enabled following configuration
    this.renderer.addClass(this.hostElement.nativeElement, 'cfg-hidden');

    this.compName$
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(cn => this.cs.getConfig(cn)),
          tap(config => {
            this.config.forEach(cfg => {
            if (this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll) {
            const inputCollection = this.hostElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#' 
            + cfg.ControlName);
          inputCollection.forEach(n => {
            // readonly is a property of inputs
            if (n.readOnly !== undefined) {
              n.readOnly = cfg.Disable;
            }
            // disabled is a property of buttons
            if (n.disabled !== undefined) {
              n.disabled = cfg.Disable;
            }
            if (cfg.Invisible) {
              this.renderer.addClass(n, 'cfg-hidden');
            }
          });
        }
      });
          })
        ).subscribe();

  }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The input property never changes (the configuration of visibility / enabling remain the same for the whole life of the component). The problem is that, because it never changes, even if I should enabled a button because some conditions are met, the button must stay disabled because it's disabled in the config.